# Dart/Flutter: resize widget on button click

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement a dashboard that has 2 widgets: a menu panel and a panel where information is displayed.
[image]

I also want that if you click the top left button, the panel would collapse and the information panel would be 100% of the screen's width.
[image]
How can I resize a widget on button click?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap you sidebar with an `AnimatedContainer`. Then, set the `width` property on that container to `width: isExpanded ? 200 : 0`, where `isExpanded` is a `bool` that specifies whether or not the sidebar should be expanded, and `200` is the `width` that you want the sidebar to be when expanded.

To toggle the sidebar to be expanded or not, simply call this:

`setState(() { isExpanded = !isExpanded; });`